# Using _wopen() under windows shell namespace extension

Tags: c++, windows, fopen, explorer

I'm developing some kind of windows shell namespace extension(NE). My extension provides custom context menu element for file and folders. Among other things I need to create a new file under my NE. I'm trying to create a file like:

```
auto flags = O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_BINARY | O_CLOEXEC;
auto fd = _wopen(L"c:\\test.txt", flags , 0666);
```

I also tryed to use `"\\?\"` prefix:

```
auto flags = O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_BINARY | O_CLOEXEC;
auto fd = _wopen(L"\\\\?\\c:\\test.txt", flags , 0666);
```

Anyway returned file descriptor is negative and errno is `EACCES` - 'Permission denied'
What am I missing?

Comment: Users cannot create files in C:\ (without elevation), did you try another location?

Comment: @Timbo I managed to do it in other location, this is right. It should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users cannot create files in C:\ (without elevation).

The shell extension runs with the credentials of the current user, so you cannot create files there.